# Solving deadlock in hand-over-hand locking a Linked list in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I'm trying to implement hand-over-hand locking in Java using a ReentrantLock that is initialized inside a Node class for a LinkedList but I seem to have deadlock and I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
// Insert value for key.
public boolean add( K key, V value ) {
    // Require key != null and value != null
    // Get hash code
    int hash = key.hashCode();
    Node pred = null, curr = null;

    try {
        pred = head;
        pred.lock.lock();
        curr = pred.next;
        curr.lock.lock();

        while( curr.hash <= hash ) {
            if( key.equals( curr.key ) ) { // key present, update value
                curr.value = value;
                return false;
            }
            pred = curr;
            pred.lock.lock();
            curr = curr.next;
            curr.lock.lock();
        }

        // key not present
        Node node = new Node( hash, key, value );
        node.next = pred.next;
        pred.next = node;

        return true;
    } finally {
        curr.lock.unlock();
        pred.lock.unlock();
    }
}
// Remove key/value pair
public boolean remove( K key ) {
    // Require key != null
    // Get hash code
    int hash = key.hashCode();
    Node pred = null, curr = null;

    try {
        // Predecessor node
        pred = this.head;
        pred.lock.lock();
        //Current node
        curr = pred.next;
        curr.lock.lock();

        // traversing list
        while( curr.hash <= hash ) {
            if( key.equals( curr.key ) ) { // key present, update value
                pred.next = curr.next;
                return true;
            }
            pred.lock.unlock();
            pred = curr;
            curr = curr.next;
            curr.lock.lock();
        }

        // key not found
        return false;
    }finally {
        curr.lock.unlock();
        pred.lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are locking nodes in while loop and you are not releasing them afterwards in add method.

Comment: http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2007-April/004076.html

Answer (score 2):

In the while loop inside add(), you actually have a couple of problems.

1. Your `pred` node doesn't get unlocked.
2. You lock the `curr` node twice.

**How does the `pred` node not get unlocked?**

```
pred = curr;
pred.lock.lock();
```

So here, you overwrite your local reference of the `pred` node, and now `pred` and `curr` both point to the same node. So before you overwrite your `pred` reference you need to ensure you are leaving that node unlocked.

**How does the `curr` node get locked twice?**

```
pred = curr;
pred.lock.lock();
```

Again, same reason as above. `pred` is the same node as your `curr` here, and you've already locked `curr` at the beginning of the method.

So calling `pred.lock.lock()` is where your deadlock happens.

**It should read:**

```
pred.lock.unlock();
pred = curr;
curr = curr.next;
curr.lock.lock();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop has two lock statements, while it should be an unlock (of pred) and a lock (of updated current).

Please contact your lecturer by e-mail.